# set One time Alarm for certain date and time Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to set One time alarm for certain Date and time. And i also set this by using alarm manager. But  My problem is when device switch off and switch on then alarm is not wake up.

My code ::

```
public void setAlarm(String initialTime, String diffTime) throws ParseException {


        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE,date);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH,month-1);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, second);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(ChatScreen.this, AlarmNotificationReceiver.class);
        i.putExtra("CoId", coId);
        i.putExtra("DeptId", deptNo);
        i.putExtra("CoName", companyName);
        i.putExtra("DpLogo", dpLogo);
        i.putExtra("DeptName",deptName);
        i.setAction("isFromAlram");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ChatScreen.this,0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),pi);
    }
```

My AlarmReceiverclass :::

```
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.e("AlarmReceiver",action);

        if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "ALARM_BOOT_COMPLETED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (action.equals("isFromAlram")) {
            Logger.errorLog("From Service", "yes");

        }
    }
}
```

and also give permission in menifest file android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"

receiver

```
android:name="com.chatapi.ChatApi.MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
```

**EDIT Here the complete manifest entry for the receiver**

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmNotificationReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:process=":remote">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="isFromAlram" > </action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Post the whole manifest entry for your `<receiver>`

Comment: In the future, please dont post code in comments. Just edit your original post and add it there. Code in comments is difficult to read :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should add logging to see if your `BroadcastReceiver` is being called on device boot. Using `Toast` for this is a bad idea, you may never get to see it. Use logging and check your logcat.

Alarms are not preserved over device boots. When the device boots, your `BroadcastReceiver` should get called. You then need to set the alarm again.